# process a text file using various delimiters

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep

My text file (unfortunately) looks like this...

```
<amar>[amar-1000#Fem$$$_Y](1){india|1000#Fem$$$,mumbai|1000#Mas$$$}
<akbar>[akbar-1000#Fem$$$_Y](1){}
<john>[-0000#$$$_N](0){USA|0100#$avi$$,NJ|0100#$avi$$}
```

It contain the customer name followed by some information. The sequence is...

text string followed by list, set and then dictionary

<> [] () {}

This is not python compatible file so the data is not as expected. I want to process the file and extract some information.

```
amar 1000 | 1000  | 1000
akbar 1000  
john 0000  | 0100 | 0100
```

1) name between <>

2) The number between - and # in the list

3 & 4) split dictionary on comma and the numbers between | and # (there can be more than 2 entries here)

I am open to using any tool best suited for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Python script will read your text file and give you the desired results:

```
import re, itertools

with open("input.txt", "r") as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        reLine = re.match(r"<(\w+)>\[(.*?)\].*?{(.*?)\}", line) 
        lNumbers = [re.findall(".*?(\d+).*?", entry) for entry in  reLine.groups()[1:]]
        lNumbers = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lNumbers))
        print reLine.group(1), " | ".join(lNumbers)
```

This prints the following output:

```
amar 1000 | 1000 | 1000
akbar 1000
john 0000 | 0100 | 0100
```

Comment: sed/ shell is good. awk is awesome. But I am accepting this solution because the actual data is more complicated and I can manage it only after splitting data using re shown here.

Answer (score 3):

As the grammer is quite complex you might find a proper parser the best solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import fileinput
from pyparsing import Word, Regex, Optional, Suppress, ZeroOrMore, alphas, nums


name = Suppress('<') + Word(alphas) + Suppress('>')
reclist = Suppress('[' + Optional(Word(alphas)) + '-') + Word(nums) + Suppress(Regex("[^]]+]"))
digit = Suppress('(' + Word(nums) + ')')
dictStart = Suppress('{')
dictVals = Suppress(Word(alphas) + '|') + Word(nums) + Suppress('#' + Regex('[^,}]+') + Optional(','))
dictEnd = Suppress('}')

parser = name + reclist + digit + dictStart + ZeroOrMore(dictVals) + dictEnd

for line in fileinput.input():
    print ' | '.join(parser.parseString(line))
```

This solution uses the [pyparsing](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) library and running produces:

```
$ python parse.py file
amar | 1000 | 1000 | 1000
akbar | 1000
john | 0000 | 0100 | 0100
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add all delimiters to the `FS` variable in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and count fields, like:

```
awk -F'[<>#|-]' '{ print $2, $4, $6, $8 }' infile
```

In case you have more than two entries between curly braces, you could use a loop to traverse all fields until the last one, like:

```
awk -F'[<>#|-]' '{ 
    printf "%s %s ", $2, $4
    for (i = 6; i <= NF; i += 2) { 
        printf "%s ", $i 
    }
    printf "\n" 
}' infile
```

Both commands yield same results:

```
amar 1000 1000 1000 
akbar 1000 
john 0000 0100 0100
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex to catch the arguments

**sample:**

```
a="<john>[-0000#$$$_N](0){USA|0100#$avi$$,NJ|0100#$avi$$}"
name=" ".join(re.findall("<(\w+)>[\s\S]+?-(\d+)#",a)[0])
others=re.findall("\|(\d+)#",a)
print name+" | "+" | ".join(others) if others else " "
```

**output:**

```
'john 0000 | 0100 | 0100'
```

**Full code:**

```
with open("input.txt","r") as inp:
     for line in inp:
          name=re.findall("<(\w+)>[\s\S]+?-(\d+)#",line)[0]
          others=re.findall("\|(\d+)#",line)
          print name+" | "+" | ".join(others) if others else " "
```

Answer (score 2):

For one line of your file :

```
test='<amar>[amar-1000#Fem$$$_Y](1){india|1000#Fem$$$,mumbai|1000#Mas$$$}'
```

replace < with empty character and remove everything after > for getting the first name

```
echo $test | sed -e 's/<//g' | sed -e 's/>.*//g'
```

get all 4 digit characters suites :

```
echo $test |  grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}'
```

replace space with your favorite separator

```
sed -e 's/ /|/g'
```

This will make :

```
echo $(echo $test | sed -e 's/<//g' | sed -e 's/>.*//g') $(echo $test |  grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}') | sed -e 's/ /|/g'
```

This will output :

amar|1000|1000|1000

with a quick script you got it : your_script.sh input_file output_file

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' #line delimiter

#empty your output file
cp /dev/null "$2"

for i in $(cat "$1"); do
    newline=`echo $(echo $i | sed -e 's/<//g' | sed -e 's/>.*//g') $(echo $i |  grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}') | sed -e 's/ /|/g'`
    echo $newline >> "$2"
done

cat "$2"
```